# understanding of Visual Studio Workloads, Components and packages

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild, package

when I'm examining some VS installer logs from different computers to check for differences
for example: dd_setup_2019123333.log:

there are some lines like:

```
> Package: Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK.MSBuildExtensions,version=15.9.28307.51,
> CurrentState: Absent, RequestedState: Present, DetectionState: Absent,
> PlannedAction: Install.
```

there will be also further entries and a `dd_setup_201911312323_Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK.MSBuildExtensions.log` file with more detailed steps.

How do I find the VS workload or components that depends on that package, so I am able to install it properly by defining VS components? Where else could I find the source of that package?

and if I want to check it vice versa:

```
> Property: InstallationWorkloads, value:
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb
```

2nd question: where do I find, what's included in e.g. `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb`?

Edit:
Answer for 2nd Q is mostly [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-and-component-ids?view=vs-2017):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please let me introduce the relationship between packages, components and workloads.

If we install a workload, some components are required by that workload to install, some are recommended and others are optional.

And if we install a component, several packages will be installed for that component.

Eg: If I install a component `"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Unity"`, apart from the  "`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Unity`" package, some packages which have dependency with it also will be installed such as "`SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Msi,version=3.9.0.3`" package.(We can find them in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages`)

> How do I find the VS workload or components that depends on that
>   package?

For most packages,  we can find which component and workload depends on it according to this document. 
However, for the package`" Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK.MSBuildExtensions"`, it seems a package which the component package depends on or in a sdk. So we can’t locate accurately which component the package belongs to because not only one component or workload depends on it.

As the picture below: We can find the workloads and components which depend on it by the log .

[image]

> Where else could I find the source of that package?

In the log, you can check if there has a download url for you to manually install it. And I find a download url(`for version=15.9.28307.272`) : 
https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/b78321cf-2968-49be-a845-fb99347d436e/f938871be0a92ffda7bf6bb1f8c2015f/payload.vsix       Hope it helps.

> Where do I find, what's included in e.g.
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb?

You can find them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2017#aspnet-and-web-development).

Comment: how did you gather the information in the log seen on the screenshot?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander Use the [Microsoft Visual Studio and .NET Framework Log Collection Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=12493) to gather the installation logs. Then we can find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder. We can find the log we need there.

Comment: @FalcoAlexander In addition, the format of your log seems similar to what the collection tool generate. So maybe you have get the right log. But the info you need like "impacted workloads,impacted components" seems to occur only when a package is failed to install. (such as [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/27649/impacted-workloads-visual-studio-core-editor-micro.html))